# Create geom_vline for mean value in a density plot, for a new variable in the dataframe, without create new tables

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-vline

Here I am looking at the `mtcars` dataset.

I create a density plot for the `wt` variable using the `ggplot2` package. I also the `geom_vline()` layer to add a vertical line for the mean of `wt`.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(mtcars$wt))
```

[image]

I then switch the syntax a bit to start with the start with the dataframe and then move to `ggplot`. I do this because I want to add a step where I create a new variable. In this example, I create `wt2` which is `wt ^ 2`.

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(wt2 = wt ^ 2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(wt2)) + 
  geom_density()
```

[image]

I find that I am no longer able to add a `geom_vline()` layer in the same way that I did before, using this new syntax. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(wt2 = wt ^ 2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(wt2)) + 
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(mtcars$wt2))
```

[image]

Now, the code below creates the graph I want, but only after creating a new table, which I want to avoid. I want to avoid this workflow because I'm working with a large dataset and it's creating memory issues to create new tables / I don't seem to have space in the environment I'm using.

mtcars_new_df <- mtcars %>%
mutate(wt2 = wt ^ 2)

mtcars_new_df %>%
ggplot(aes(wt2)) +
geom_density() +
geom_vline(xintercept = mean(mtcars$wt2))

[image]

The reason I want to avoid a workflow where I create a new dataframe is because of memory and time issues. (I'm using a dataset much larger than the `mtcars` dataset.)

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use `stat_summary` to compute the mean of the variable mapped on `x` like so:

Note: As `stat_summary` by default applies on the variable mapped on `y` we have to set `orientation="y"` to compute the mean of `x`. Additionally `stat_summary` requires both an `x` and an `y` so I set that latter to `0` which should be fine for `geom_density`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(wt2 = wt ^ 2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(wt2)) + 
  geom_density() +
  stat_summary(aes(xintercept = ..x.., y = 0), fun = mean, geom = "vline", orientation = "y")
```

[image]

A second example with the original `wt`:

```r
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(wt)) + 
  geom_density() +
  stat_summary(aes(xintercept = after_stat(x), y = 0), fun = mean, geom = "vline", orientation = "y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we could do it:
The idea is to get access to the intermediate save!

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(wt2 = wt ^ 2) %>%
  {. ->>intermediateResult} %>%   # this saves intermediate 
  ggplot(aes(wt2)) + 
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(intermediateResult$wt2))
```

[image]

Comment: I think OP specifically wanted to avoid intermediate computations due to performance issues.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your valuable comment. I thought the idea was to keep in pipe without interrupting, but I don't know exactly. We will see if the OP likes or not.